# Typo in throttle violation error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, api

I was just playing around with the API locally and got throttled for the `questions` and `answers` methods (the only two I was using).

Anyway, I noticed there’s a small typo in the error message that’s returned:

```
{"error_id":502,"error_name":"throttle_violation","error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more requests availabe in 61920 seconds"}
```

“availabe” should probably be “available”.

P.S. I was very surprised to get banned from using those two methods *for over 18 hours*, considering I was just testing some stuff locally. I must be a horrible coder :)

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice for developers to have a special page somewhere where we can reset the timeout when we accidentally trigger it.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison That would be nice, indeed! Should I post a new topic with a feature request? (This one is just about the typo.)

Comment: Certainly - go right ahead.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Done: http://stackapps.com/q/3265/2384 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These typos will be fixed in the next deploy.