# Add a special page where developers can reset throttle timeouts

Tags: feature-request, api, rate-limit

As George Edison [noted](https://stackapps.com/q/3264/2384#comment7735_3264), it would be useful to have a special page where developers can reset the throttle timeout when we accidentally trigger it.

This happened to me [this morning](https://stackapps.com/q/3264/2384) — I got banned for over 18 hours just by doing some quick *local* testing, performing just 2 API calls per page view (I was refreshing at most every second or so).

**Update:** The same thing just happened again. I didn’t even get a `backoff` warning in the last request that still gave a proper response. [The docs on throttling](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) say:

> Every application is subject to an IP based concurrent request throttle. If a single IP is making more than 30 requests a second, new requests will be dropped. The exact ban period is subject to change, but will be on the order of 30 seconds to a few minutes typically.

1. There’s no way I was making 30 requests a second. This was a local test page; only I could use it. Every time I clicked a button two requests were made, that’s it. I’m unable to click 30 times in one second.
2. This is the second time I’ve gotten a ~17 hour (~61,200 seconds) ban. Not really on the order of 30 seconds, right? :)

Anyhow, if I’m doing anything wrong, I’d love to hear what it is. But to me, this seems like a bug.